# How do I solve the integral $\int\frac{\tan x}{\sin^2x+2\cos^2x}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So I need to solve the integral

> $$\int  \frac { \tan { x }  }{ \left( \sin { x }  \right) ^{ 2 }+2\left( \cos { x }  \right) ^{ 2 } } dx$$

I saw some exercises that suggest I need to use the secant function to solve it but can I do it without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int  \frac { \tan { x }  }{ \left( \sin { x }  \right) ^{ 2 }+2\left( \cos { x }  \right) ^{ 2 } } dx=\int  \frac { \tan { x }  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ x } \left( 2+\tan ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right)  } dx=\int  \frac { \tan { x }  }{ \left( 2+\tan ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right)  } d\tan { x } \\ $$
then sunstitute $z=\tan { x } $ so that
$$\\ =\int  \frac { z }{ 2+{ z }^{ 2 } } dz=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int { \frac { d\left( 2+{ z }^{ 2 } \right)  }{ 2+{ z }^{ 2 } }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \ln { \left( 2+{ z }^{ 2 } \right) +C = } \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \ln { \left( 2+\tan ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right) +C } $$

Comment: I solved it and I got that it is equal to $\frac{ln(tan^2x+2)}{2}$. Is it right?

Comment: @OvyOvy,yes it is correct

Comment: @user236182,thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\tan t$ and then
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int \frac{\tan x}{(\sin x)^2+2(\cos x)^2}dx\\
&=&\int \frac{\tan x}{\tan^2 x+2}\sec^2x dx\\
&=&\int\frac{u}{u^2+2}du
\end{eqnarray}
and you can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{\tan x}{(\sin x)^2+2(\cos x)^2}dx=-\int\frac{1}{\cos{x}(1+\cos^2x)}d(\cos{x})=$$
$$=\int\left(\frac{\cos{x}}{1+\cos^2x}-\frac{1}{\cos{x}}\right)d(\cos{x})=\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\cos^2x)-\ln|\cos{x}|+C.$$

Comment: This is a new low: posting answers before they are completed, on purpose. Shame on you.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you use $cosx=t$?

Comment: @gbox It's not necessary. I'll delete this thing. See now please.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int\frac{\tan x}{\sin^2x+2\cos^2x}\,dx
&= \int\dfrac{1}{1+\cos^2x}\dfrac{1}{\cos x}\sin x\,dx \\
&= \int\left(\dfrac{1}{\cos x}-\dfrac{\cos x}{1+\cos^2x}\right)\sin x\,dx \\
&= -\ln\cos x+\dfrac12\ln(1+\cos^2x)+C
\end{align}